# Getting data from 3 table with different information

Tags: mysql, sql

Please respect I'am new in SQL programming.
Here is my problem, I have 3 different tables and each table have different information

**Table1:** Name, userid, kycid, taskid, loanid, summary
**Table2:** userid, reasonid, kycid, taskid
**Table3:** reasonid, reasonsummary

I want to have a result showing the following: Name, userid, kycid, taskid, loanid, summary, reasonid, reasonsummary

each reason id have there corresponding reason summary:

Example:
Reasonid: Reasonsummary
1 = Requested to cancel
2 = Age Not qualified

Comment: What have you tried and where did it not work right?

Comment: I'm confuse if I will use Join or Sub-query.

Comment: What is the exact problem? You can't *join* tables in the right way? You can't output the correct data in the required format? You have strange syntax in the query?

Comment: Try both , publish what you tried and explain what went wrong if anything. and read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I'm confuse if I will use Join or Sub-query since i will get the data from 3 different table where 1st table and 2nd table i can only link is userid and kycid.

Comment: Both ways (join and subquery) should do; *join* seems to be more natural

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example data:

```
create table Table1 (Name varchar(50), userid int, kycid int, taskid int, loanid int, summary int);

create table Table2 (userid int, reasonid int, kycid int, taskid int);

create table Table3 (reasonid int, reasonsummary int);

insert into Table1 values('Name1', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
insert into Table1 values('Name2', 2, 3, 3, 4, 5);


insert into Table2 values(1, 33, 44, 55);
insert into Table2 values(3, 66, 44, 55);


insert into Table3 values(33, 55);
insert into Table3 values(55, 55);
```

You can try something like this:

```
Select t1.Name
       , t1.userid
       , t1.kycid
       , t1.taskid
       , t1.loanid
       , t1.summary
       , t2.reasonid
       , t3.reasonsummary
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.userid = t2.userid
left join table3 t3 on t2.reasonid = t3.reasonid;
```

But note that all the questions other useras asked are valid and you should add a lot more details when asking a question. Hope this will help.

Here is the demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f736ce/1

Comment: You are welcome, I am happy to help. If this helped you , you can mark the answer as the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select t1.Name
      , t1.userid
      , t1.kycid
      , t1.taskid
      , t1.loanid
      , t1.summary
      , t2.reasonid
      , t3.reasonsummary 
 from table1 t1 
      , table2 t2
      , table3 t3
 where t1.userid=t2.userid 
 and t2.reasonid=t3.reasonid
```

Try this.